# making 3 piece button come together properly in css

Tags: css, button, imagebutton

Ok, So I have 6 files in total.

button_01.png (left side of the button)

button_01-RO.png (role over)

button_02.png (middle)

button_02-RO.png (role over)

button_03.png (right side of the button)

button_03-RO.png (role over)

below is a link to the images. They are listed in the order above.
    http://imgur.com/fPIkNAW
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/zunch.jpg
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTHAq.jpg
    http://imgur.com/BsT6WiI
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkWuH.jpg
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0bhN.jpg

Here is the Fiddle link
    http://jsfiddle.net/gC2L3/

I have the below code. But the left and right image is not setting in the right place. It's just going over top of the text. I'm very new at doing this level of buttons. I've search everywhere on how to do this and I've not been able to find a way to do it with the role over. And my attempt below is clearly not working. Everyone here has always been very helpful. I'm hoping someone here will know how to do this. I've spent over 4 hours trying different things to get this to work and now I give up and hoping someone here can help. Please and Thank you. Everything works, just the left and right are not placed properly.

```
<style>
li.link-button {
float: left;
background: url('/opserv/assets/button_02.png') repeat-x;
}
.link-button a {
font-family: Arial;
color: White;
text-decoration: none;
background: url('/opserv/assets/button_01.png') left no-repeat;
}
.link-button span {
padding-left: 8px;
padding-right: 8px;
background: url('/opserv/assets/button_03.png') right no-repeat;
}
li.link-button:hover {
float: left;
background: url('/opserv/assets/button_02-RO.png') repeat-x;
}
.link-button:hover a {
font-family: Arial;
color: White;
text-decoration: none;
background: url('/opserv/assets/button_01-RO.png') left no-repeat;
}
.link-button:hover span {
padding-left: 8px;
padding-right: 8px;
background: url('/opserv/assets/button_03-RO.png') right no-repeat;
}
</style>

<ul>
<li class="link-button">
<a href="#"><span>Press Me</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perhaps you can start by creating a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Sorry, added the fiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Did some more research and actually found the answer. Hopefully this will help someone in the future. you'll have to change the height and width to patch your images.

```
.selector{
color: white;
position: relative;
height: 24px;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0 11px;
border: 0;
background: url('Center.png') repeat-x;
}
.selector::before,
.selector::after {
content: ' ';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 11px;
height: 24px;
}
.selector::before {
left: -11px;
background: url('Left.png') left no-repeat;
}
.selector::after {
right: -11px;
background: url('Right.png') right no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A small jQuery script would do it.  You could use something like this: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: I don't see how this helps me make a 3 button image come together properly in css. I'm not looking to toggle the class of the button. Maybe I am misunderstanding how to use the function you are providing.

Comment: By changing the class of the button parts when you mouse over one part, you can assign different css to each.  So if when you mouseover one part, all three have the class "hovered" added to it, in your css file .hovered can be acted upon.